# Merge {write} and {write-file}

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there any distinction between [write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write) and [write-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file), or can they be merged?

Comment: We have the clumsily named [filesystem-access](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file+filesystem-access) tag as well.

Comment: @Charles: 'filesystem-access' can be more general, incl. reading files. It might be not that bad to have it around.

Comment: @Martin: Could it be called just [filesystem]?  Could the two writing tags be synonyms for it?  I'm not sure what's best.

Comment: @Charles: I would prefer to have one specific write tag. Tagging questions with (too) general tags would weaken their benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mind merging them. Please vote for this answer if you agree.

I would suggest the [write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write) tag as master tag and merge [write-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file) into it incl. making it a synonym. We could also create another synonym [write-register](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-register) to make sure that one doesn't pop up.